# Restricting posts to a specifc category and subcategory

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

On this site: http://www.palmbeachwoman.com/stories/ I used a programmer to customize the template. His code for this page is:

```
<?php 

$args = array( 'numberposts' => 18,   'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");

$postslist = get_posts( $args );

echo '<ul id="latest_stories">';

foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>">

<span class="s_thumb"> <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?> </span>

<span class="s_title"> <?php the_title(); ?> </span></a>

<span class="s_cotegories">More Stories from <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></span></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The posts were supposed to be restricted to a specific category (#82) and any subcategories within it. I know how to do this with the traditional post display: http://alijafarian.com/how-to-display-wordpress-posts-for-a-specific-category/ but since I didn't write this code, I'm not sure how to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the category in the array past to get_posts

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 18, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",
'orderby'=>"post_date", category=>82);
```